# Show custom label on input with Jquery Autocomplete when focus with arrowkeys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How can I override default behavior of displaying item label on the input when hovering/focusing on the items results?

Example not working:

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    focus: function(event, ui){
         console.log("print")
         $(this).val('my custom label to show in input');    
    }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="ac"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34fSg/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Prevent the default action of the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), which is to replace the input's value with the focused item's value:

```
$('#ac').autocomplete({
    source : ["hello", "how", "do", "you", "do"],
    focus: function(event, ui){
         this.value = 'my custom label to show in input';
         event.preventDefault(); // <-----
    }
})
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4jJyb/

Comment: Thanks! Always forget this 'hack'